# Changing language

Tags: bastion

I have purchased Bastion among other games with the Humble Indie Bundle 9 and I'd like to play the game in English, but for some reason the game is in German. Is there any way to change the language to English?

I haven't found any language settings in the menu and I have set my Humble account to state my residency to United Kingdom thinking that might make a difference, but while the installer is in English and doesn't offer a language selection either, the game is in German.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://www.gog.com/forum/general/changing_language_in_bastion), you can use the command-line parameter `-lang en` to change the language to English. The site also suggests that the game checks your OS language when starting the game, so changing your Windows to English should also do the trick.

A third option is to use Steam, where you can use the language setting directly:

[image: Steam Language menu - Bastion Properties]